# Cambiar clase css dinamicamente en javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Quiero cambiar el valor de una propiedad de una clase css dinamicamente con javaScript

Por ejemplo teniendo:

```js
$(".miClase").css("visibility", "visible");
```

```css
.miClase {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="miClase">hola</p>
```

Comment: Ahí no se está cambiando la clase, se está asignando un valor a una propiedad de CSS. ¿qué es lo que deseas hacer entonces?

Comment: Ya corregí el enunciado gracias !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías probar con usar:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('miClase');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
{
    elems[i].style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Comment: Correcto, gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Para cambiar **estilos**, que es lo que buscas, es de la siguiente manera:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.property = new style
```

**Ejemplo**

```
document.getElementById("idElemento").style.visibility= "visible";
```

**Ejemplo en tu caso:**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("miClase").style.visibility= "visible";
```

Comment: No entiendo quien votó positivo a esta respuesta, pero no está respondiendo correctamente según lo que plantea el OP.

Comment: El dijo una clase, pero con el ejemplo que dio con JQuery se refería a cambiar un estilo. Así que si esta correcto, o me puedes decir en que pide ayuda? 
Digo, a lo mejor estoy entendiendo mal.

Comment: Se está cambiando el valor de una propiedad a una clase, no a un id, son selectores distintos.

Comment: vale, solo era cambiar una cosa, listo

Comment: *getElementsByClassName* no trae un arreglo ?

Answer (score 1):

En el caso en el cual quieres cambiar la visibilidad del primer elemento cuya clase es `miClase` puedes optar para una de estas soluciones:

1. ```
   document.querySelector(".miClase").style.visibility = "visible";
   ```
2. ```
   document.querySelectorAll(".miClase")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
   ```
3. ```
   getElementsByClassName('miClase')[0].style.visibility = "visible";
   ```

Si por de otra parte quieres cambiar la visibilidad de todos los elementos cuya clase es `miClase` puedes hacer lo que sugirió @GermánMartínez o puedes utilizar de la misma manera `querySelectorAll`.